# Retrieve <TD> text using WATIR

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using WATIR for automated testing, and I need to copy in a variable the value of a rate. In the example below (from webpage source code), I need that variable `myrate` has value `2.595`. I know how to retrieve value from `<input>` or `<span>` (see below), but not directly from a `<td>`. Any help? Thanks

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD>Rate</TD>
    <TD>2.595</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

For a `<span>` I use this code:

```
raRetrieved = browser.span(:name => 'myForm.raNumber').text
```

Comment: posting actual sample HTML from your page, instead of something generic, will tend to get you better answers as we can better see the actual challenge you are facing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this, find the row you want using a regular expression to match a row that contains the word 'Rate', then get the text of the third cell in the row.

```
myrate = browser.tr(:text, /Rate/).td(:index => 2).text
 #or you can use the more user-friendly aliases for those tags
myrate = browser.row(:text, /Rate/).cell(:index => 2).text
```

If the word 'Rate' might appear elsewhere in other textin that table, but is always just the only entry in the second cell of the row you want, then find the cell with that exact text, use the parent method to locate the row that holds that cell , and then get the text from the third cell.

```
myrate = browser.cell(:text, 'Rate').parent.cell(:index => 2).text
```

use of `.cell` & `.row` vs `.td` & `.tr`  is up to you, some people prefer the tags, others like the more descriptive names.  Use whatever you feel makes the code the most readable for you or others who will work with it.

Note: code above presumes use of Watir-Webdriver, or Watir 2.x which both use zero based indexing.  For older versions of Watir, change the index values to 3

And for the record I totally agree with comments of others about the lack of testability of the code sample you posted. it's horrid.  Asking for something to locate the proper elements, such as ID values or Names is not out of line in terms of making the page easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
browser.td(how, what).text
```

The problem here is that `table`, `tr` and `td` tags do not have any attributes. You can try something like this (not tested):

```
browser.table[0][2].text
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the table is much larger might change very often, including the order of the rows. Is it possible to get somehow the index of the "Rate" <td> (this text never changes) and then request the text of the next <td> (2.595) and store it in the variable?

Comment: @Arturo You may have higher-level problems; talk to dev, or talk to your boss or talk to your client (or if you're on your own, talk to yourself) about making the front end more testable, and examine your investment in brittle automation scripts. For a decent-sized project, in a month or two, you will be in code maintenance hell. You might be able to find it with browser.span(:text=>'Rate', :index=>X) then use .parent for the row, then use the index of that row (unless that changes too). Ooh, or parse it out of the row text with regex. Some ideas, anyway.

Comment: @kinofrost  agree on both counts.   The answer I posted a little while ago covers a few of those ideas (regex to find via text, and using the parent method if the easiest thing to do is find the cell with specific text.  )

Answer (score 1):

If this helps to anyone who is having the same issue, it is working for me like this:

```
browser.td(:text => "Rate").parent.cell(:index, 2).text
```

Thank you all